# Authentication issue running search command in private docker registry

Tags: docker, windows-registry, private

I'm setting up a private Docker registry using the official image. I have started an instance using the following docker-compose file:

```
registry:
  restart: always
  image: registry:2.3.1
  ports:
    - 5000:5000
  environment:
    REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/domain.crt
    REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/domain.key
    REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
    REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/htpasswd
    REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry Realm
    SEARCH_BACKEND: sqlalchemy
    SQLALCHEMY_INDEX_DATABASE: sqlite:////opt/sqlitedb/reg.db
  volumes:
    - /docker/registry/data:/var/lib/registry
    - /docker/registry/certs:/certs
    - /docker/registry/auth:/auth
    - /docker/registry/search:/opt/sqlitedb
```

I can login fine:

```
root@domain:/home/foo# docker login registry.domain.com:5000
Username (foo): foo
Password: 
WARNING: login credentials saved in /root/.docker/config.json
Login Succeeded
```

I can push images to the private registry without any problem:

```
root@domain:/home/foo# docker tag hello-world registry.domain.com:5000/hello-world
root@domain:/home/foo# docker push registry.domain.com:5000/hello-world
The push refers to a repository [registry.domain.com:5000/hello-world]
5f70bf18a086: Layer already exists 
b652ec3a27e7: Layer already exists 
latest: digest: sha256:fea8895f450959fa676bcc1df0611ea93823a735a01205fd8622846041d0c7cf size: 708
```

What I can't do is search:

```
root@domain:/home/foo# docker search registry.domain.com:5000/hello
Error response from daemon: Unexpected status code 404
```

The docker instance spits this out:

```
registry_1 | time="2016-04-04T22:38:59Z" level=warning msg="error authorizing context: basic authentication challenge for realm \"Registry Realm\": invalid authorization credential" go.version=go1.5.3 http.request.host="registry.domain.com:5000" http.request.id=2f158656-545d-4cd0-a0a1-2d18f01843a4 http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:57196" http.request.uri="/v2/" http.request.useragent="docker/1.10.3 go/go1.5.3 git-commit/20f81dd kernel/4.2.0-27-generic os/linux arch/amd64" instance.id=cc656ad8-63a4-499e-bbde-ad797059e39e version=v2.3.1 
registry_1 | 172.17.0.1 - - [04/Apr/2016:22:38:59 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 401 87 "" "docker/1.10.3 go/go1.5.3 git-commit/20f81dd kernel/4.2.0-27-generic os/linux arch/amd64"
registry_1 | time="2016-04-04T22:38:59Z" level=warning msg="error authorizing context: basic authentication challenge for realm \"Registry Realm\": invalid authorization credential" go.version=go1.5.3 http.request.host="registry.domain.com:5000" http.request.id=6dcbc494-62b9-4f32-9c70-fece7c61a90b http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:57200" http.request.uri="/v2/" http.request.useragent="docker/1.10.3 go/go1.5.3 git-commit/20f81dd kernel/4.2.0-27-generic os/linux arch/amd64" instance.id=cc656ad8-63a4-499e-bbde-ad797059e39e version=v2.3.1 
registry_1 | 172.17.0.1 - - [04/Apr/2016:22:38:59 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 401 87 "" "docker/1.10.3 go/go1.5.3 git-commit/20f81dd kernel/4.2.0-27-generic os/linux arch/amd64"
registry_1 | 172.17.0.1 - - [04/Apr/2016:22:38:59 +0000] "GET /v1/search?q=hellow HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "" "docker/1.10.3 go/go1.5.3 git-commit/20f81dd kernel/4.2.0-27-generic os/linux arch/amd64"
```

I spent a few hours researching this. The 404 points to the Indexing service sqlalchemy not being deployed. After going through the latest version of [registry configuration reference](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/), it seems that the Search Backend section is no longer valid. So maybe the SEARCH_BACKEND env variable on my docker-compose file is being ignored and indexation is not being done (the /opt/sqlitedb folder is empty).

On the other hand, the error suggests this is an authentication issue.

Maybe the problem lies in differences between v1 and v2 of the registry. I have no prior experience with the registry so I think I'm missing something here.
What do I need to do to have docker search working on my private registry?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `curl`-

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5001/v1/search?q=image_name
```

It will give you result in json format.

Please check old post [How to search images from private registry ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733678/how-to-search-images-from-private-1-0-registry-in-docker)